# Problem Trying to get property 'num_row' of non-object in and Undefined variable: stmt_result in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem when i am try to check user and password from database while login it keep
reply an error message :

Notice: Trying to get property 'num_row' of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/studyact/login.php on line 27
User name or Password is incorrect, please check and try again.

i type user and password correct! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtiIZ.png)

php file :

```
<?php

//html 
  $user_staff = $_POST["user_staff"];
  $pass_staff = $_POST["pass_staff"];


// Create connection



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db ="studyact";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}else{
   $stmt =$con-> prepare("select * from loginstaff where user_staff = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_staff);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmtresult = $stmt->get_result();
   if($stmtresult-> num_row > 0){
      $data = $stmtresult-> fetch_assoc();
       if($data["pass_staff"] === $pass_staff){
          echo "<h2>Login Successfully</h2>";
    }
    else{
          echo "<h2> Sorry User name or Password is incorrect.</h2>";
      }
  
    }else{
        echo "<h2> User name or Password is incorrect, please check and try again.</h2>";
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: `$stmtresult` is not `$stmt_result`.

Comment: updated but still

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo on line 27 
if($stmtresult->num_row**s** > 0)

`mysqli_stmt::$num_rows — Returns the number of rows fetched from the server`